# Rails 3.0 has_many and belongs_to associations headache.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many, belongs-to

Currently learning Rails, so be gentle.

I want to check that i'm getting this right before I go to far:

Building an app that allows our 'Customers' to log in, and create a quote. 'Suppliers' (in this case conference venue owners) can then look a the quotes, and reply to them with a proposal, which the customer will be able to view. Each Supplier account will have the option to have one or more 'Venues' that belong to it (if they run a chain of venues for instance), and each proposal made will be from a specific venue.

Other complicated issues that I will probably come across later on, does this look right as far as the relationships go?

P.S I realise that the below is not actually code that will work, I just laid it out like this whilst I attempt to get my head around it.

```
Customer (will be a type of user)
has_many :quotes
has_many :proposals, :through => :venue

Supplier (will be a type of user)
has_many :venues
has_many :proposals, :through => :venue

Venue
belongs_to :supplier 
has_many Proposals

Quote
belongs_to :customer

Proposal
belongs_to :venue
```

And the basic tables:

```
Customer
    id

Supplier
    id

Quote
    id
    customer_id

Venue
    id
    supplier_id

Proposal
    id
    venue_id
```

There might be a much better way to do this, using has_ones and has_and_belongs_to_many etc, but i've no idea.

Thanks

Comment: How do you want `customers` to be related with `venues`? 'Cause if you want `customers` to have many `proposals` through `venues`, `customers` should also have many `venues`.

Comment: Customers could pick up proposals from any venue - perhaps I don't need the through's? Could I remove both of those?

Comment: So you should remove `:through` at least from `Customer has_many :proposals`. How do you want your `suppliers` connected with proposals?

Comment: Each supplier would have many proposals - but each proposal would be from a specific venue, and each venue would belong to a certain supplier. (I could have done away with the 'venue' model, but it  stops suppliers having to sign up to the site for each venue they own - I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think it should look like this:

```
Customer
  has_many :quotes
  has_many :proposals

Supplier
  has_many :venues
  has_many :proposals, :through => :venues

Venue
  belongs_to :supplier 
  has_many :proposals

Quote
  belongs_to :customer

Proposal
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :customer
```

and in db schema:

```
Customer
  id

Supplier
  id

Quote
  id
  customer_id

Venue
  id
  supplier_id

Proposal
  id
  venue_id
  customer_id
```